# Joomla images gallery management

Tags: joomla-3.x, extensions

I'm looking for a Joomla extension to display an image gallery in articles. Most extensions I've seen render the gallery from a folder where the pictures are, so If I had 40 articles with galleries, I would have 40 different folders, and suppose that I want to reuse some pictures of one of the gallery folders I would have to copy and paste them in another folder, so I will have the same picture 2 times, and not to say if I want that picture in 50 differents galleries!

Example: suppose I´m writing an article and I want to put some images in it and make a gallery, so I click the "gallery button" and it opens an images browser where all my pictures are (on the server), each picture has a checkbox to tell the "gallery render engine" which pictures to show, so I choose the ones which I like most and the gallery is displayed!!! Of course the image browser has to have a button to upload images from my computer to the server...

I hope you understand what my needs are... so the question is: is there an extension that can do this??

Answer (score 2):

This seems to do everything you need. I use it on many websites and it makes re-using image galleries very easy without the need to copy and paste images or create new folders, which I think is your main requirement?

[Simple Image Gallery](http://www.joomlaworks.net/extensions/free/simple-image-gallery)

Taken from their website;

The plugin can turn any folder of images located inside your Joomla website into a grid-style image gallery with cool lightbox previews. Using tag like {gallery}myphotos{/gallery}.

So for example, if we have a folder called "my_trip_to_Paris" located in images/stories/my_trip_to_Paris, then we can create our gallery by simply entering the tag {gallery}my_trip_to_Paris{/gallery} into some Joomla article.

I hope this helps!

Comment: hi johnny... first of all thank you for the answer to my problem... but perhaps I didn´t explain myself well... the simple image gallery manages the gallery, like you said, from a specific folder (my_trip_to_paris for example). Now lets say that I want to make another gallery called "my_trips" where I want to put some of the pictures of places where I´ve been, so if I need SOME pictures from "my_trip_to_paris" I would need to copy and paste them on "my trips" folder... and there´s where my problem is, the repited images...

Comment: extra info: the website I´m working with is for a digital newspaper... 
there is an admin (me) who manage the backend, and there are "journalist" who work from the frontend... they are responsible for making the articles..

What I need is to have ONE folder where ALL the pictures are. If a journalist is writing an article and he wants to add some pictures to it, he just need to click on the image´s button and select them from that UNIQUE folder... then they will be sown like a gallery in the article... or in a LIGHTBOX

Answer (score 2):

Your requirements are quite specific, you might have to modify them a little in order to find a good solution.

One option might be [Phoca Gallery](http://www.phoca.cz/phocagallery). I haven't used it in a while, so it might not work exactly as you require, but as far as I remember your users can [upload images from the frontend](http://www.phoca.cz/documents/2-phoca-gallery-component/20-user-upload), and add images inside any article using the [Phoca Gallery Plugin](http://www.phoca.cz/documents/14-phoca-gallery-plugin/58-displaying-phoca-gallery-plugin). You probably have to go through the settings to get everything correctly set up.

Have you had a look at [RokGallery](http://www.rockettheme.com/joomla/extensions/rokgallery)? The slideshow is displayed through a module, so your users won't be able to manage it from the front-end, but you can handle all the images from the back-end, set up as many modules as you need, and load it into any article using `{loadposition CUSTOMPOSITION}`. The extension works using a tag system, so you can add one or more tags to your images, thus including one image in several galleries.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Widgetkit from Yootheme. Im my opinion is the best component to create multiple Gallery. You can use the gallery in any part of your content using tags like [widgetkit id="xx"]. With this, you can use paragraph text, gallery and paragraph text again.

http://yootheme.com/demo/widgetkit/joomla/index.php/home/gallery

Answer (score 0):

sigplus Image Gallery and the gallery in YT Shortcode are a couple of example extensions where you can limit the images displayed in the gallery to specific images rather than the whole folder:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/sigplus

http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/yt-shortcode

See the advanced instructions for sigplus at: http://hunyadi.info.hu/levente/en/sigplus/advanced